# react router v4 dployment on ec2 return 404

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My local React & Node.js app is working locally, but all React routes are failing on the server.

On the server (aws) index.html would show, and I also receive positive feedback trying to authenticate with user & password (so I assume all is fine with node.js routes).
but all the React Router inner paths  would "404".

the main React routing page look like this:

```
import { Redirect, BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' render={() => (<Login setRedirect={this.setRedirect} />)} />
          <Route exact path='/edit-menu' component={EditMenu} />
          <Route path='/view-menu/:rest_id' component={ViewMenu} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
```

after successful login the page will forward to:
*serverhostname*:8081/edit-menu (as on localhost)

I would expect the hostname/edit-menu to show to component of EditMenu, as it does on localhost, but returns "404" on the server.

Git: https://github.com/Yanipo5/MenuCreator
Note: I red https://stanko.github.io/react-router-subfolder-on-server/
and it says it relates to the dev server trying to map routes to the root directory???? not sure but any way currently my server project structure is (root <- ec2-user <- myProjectDirectory)

Answer (score 0):

Added node.js to capture and redirect all static call to the index.html

```
// handle every other route with index.html, which will contain // a
script tag to your application's JavaScript file(s). 

app.get('*', function (request, response){  
response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html')) })
```

farther read:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.0.0-rc5/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#configuring-your-server